# regex simplify ending string

Tags: regex, regex-group

What is a smarter way of doing this?

```
^word$|^word.php$|^word.asp$|^word.html$|^word.htm$
```

I can't figure out how to properly group regex so as not to repeat things.

Comment: Factoring has a history in math, nothing's weird: `^word(?:\.(?:html?|asp|php))?$`

Comment: you can make any sequence within the regex optional, as revo has done, with a `?` after parentheses `(pattern)`

Comment: What about `.*` to catch all?: `^word.*$`